# How do I create a user in the backend and allow them to only view?

Tags: user-roles, user, admin-user

They are allowed to view everything but not edit anything... Is this possible?

Here's what the function looks like now, perhaps i did something wrong?

```
    public function preDispatch()
{
    // override admin store design settings via stores section
    Mage::getDesign()
        ->setArea($this->_currentArea)
        ->setPackageName((string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('stores/admin/design/package/name'))
        ->setTheme((string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('stores/admin/design/theme/default'))
    ;
    foreach (array('layout', 'template', 'skin', 'locale') as $type) {
        if ($value = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode("stores/admin/design/theme/{$type}")) {
            Mage::getDesign()->setTheme($type, $value);
        }
    }

    $this->getLayout()->setArea($this->_currentArea);

    Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_controller_action_predispatch_start', array());
    parent::preDispatch();
    $_isValidFormKey = true;
    $_isValidSecretKey = true;
    $_keyErrorMsg = '';
    if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $_isValidFormKey = $this->_validateFormKey();
            $_keyErrorMsg = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.');
        } elseif (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->useSecretKey()) {
            $_isValidSecretKey = $this->_validateSecretKey();
            $_keyErrorMsg = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Invalid Secret Key. Please refresh the page.');
        }
    }
    if (!$_isValidFormKey || !$_isValidSecretKey) {
        $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_POST_DISPATCH, true);
        if ($this->getRequest()->getQuery('isAjax', false) || $this->getRequest()->getQuery('ajax', false)) {
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode(array(
                'error' => true,
                'message' => $_keyErrorMsg
            )));
        } else {
            $this->_redirect( Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getStartupPageUrl() );
        }
        return $this;
    }

    $_acl_user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser();
    if($_acl_user &&  $_acl_user->getId()) $_acl_role_id = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getRoles();
    else
       $_acl_role_id = 0;
    if($_acl_role_id > 0)
       $_acl_role = Mage::getModel('admin/roles')->load($_acl_role_id)->getRoleName();
    else
       $_acl_role = 'None';

    if($this->getRequest()->isDispatched() && $this->getRequest()->getActionName() !== 'denied' && (!$this->_isAllowed() || ($_acl_role == 'ReadOnlyAccess'
    && preg_match('/(add|reset|generate|save|update\delete)/' ,$this->getRequest()->getActionName()))) ) {
      $this->_forward('denied');
      $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
      return $this;
    }




    if ($this->getRequest()->isDispatched()
        && $this->getRequest()->getActionName() !== 'denied'
        && !$this->_isAllowed()) {
        $this->_forward('denied');
        $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        return $this;
    }

    if (!$this->getFlag('', self::FLAG_IS_URLS_CHECKED)
        && !$this->getRequest()->getParam('forwarded')
        && !$this->_getSession()->getIsUrlNotice(true)
        && !Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/can_use_base_url')) {
        //$this->_checkUrlSettings();
        $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_IS_URLS_CHECKED, true);
    }
    if (is_null(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getLocale())) {
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setLocale(Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode());
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this `read-only` change for Magento 1 a while ago.

What you need:

1. create backend permission role with the name `ReadOnlyAccess`
2. create backend user and assign `ReadOnlyAccess` role to it
3. overwrite `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action` class `preDispatch` function to filter denied actions:

   ```
    cp app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php \
   app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php


   187  $_acl_user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')
                         ->getUser();
   188  if($_acl_user && $_acl_user->getId())
   189    $_acl_role_id =
           Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')
               ->getUser()
               ->getRoles();
   190  else
   191    $_acl_role_id = 0;
   192  if($_acl_role_id > 0)
   193     $_acl_role = Mage::getModel('admin/roles')
        ->load($_acl_role_id)->getRoleName();
   194  else
   195     $_acl_role = 'None';

   196  if ($this->getRequest()->isDispatched()
   197         && $this->getRequest()->getActionName()
               !== 'denied'
   198     && (!$this->_isAllowed() ||
      ($_acl_role == 'ReadOnlyAccess'
    && preg_match('/(add|reset|generate|save|update|delete)/'
         ,$this->getRequest()->getActionName())))    ) {
   199        $this->_forward('denied');
   200        $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
   201        return $this;
   202  }
   ```
4. Clear Magento cache:

   ```
   rm -rf var/cache/*
   ```

Originally published as https://www.goivvy.com/blog/magento-admin-backend-read-only-access-role

Comment: Thank you @Konstantin Gerasimov. I'm using Magento ver. 1.14.2.4
and you would think they would of built something like this before out of the box.

Comment: I agree. They could've I think it should work more or less the same for EE 1.14 give it a try

Comment: Why doesn't any of the if or else statements have brackets? { }

Comment: Gerasimov, please have a look at my code above. It doesn't seem to be working for me. Thank you.

Comment: Looks to be OK. does the user have ReadOnlyAccess role? put die("ok") in this file - does it display ok? is that the correct file you put code in app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php ?

Comment: Yes, the file is in that directory. I had to build out that directory structure in local and i placed Action.php in there. Where should i put the die('ok'); before the return $this; or after or does it matter?

Comment: @KonstantinGerasimov how same thing can be achieved in Magento2